# Is it a good practice to directly JSON.stringify Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I have data-structures that are defined as Javascript objects. I like to stringify them to send over network. Merely calling `JSON.stringify()` on them seems to work. But is it a good practice?

Are there any special cases where this may break (for example static methods?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a subset of JS, so from that standpoint, it's 100% fine.

JSON is also intended to be converted into JS to be operated on, and converted back, to be sent out, or stored.

So turning an object into JSON is part of the intended purpose, rather than having to write all JSON by hand.

In terms of special cases, JSON can contain **no** functions, no circular references... nothing other than strings, numbers and booleans, inside of nested objects and arrays.

If that's already the format your data is in, you're done.

IE6 and 7 don't have native JSON support.
However, json2.js is the file from Douglas Crockford which all of the native implementations are based on.
If `!window.JSON` then load that file, and it will work just fine, in OldIE.

Comment: Does it mean `JSON.stringify` will consistently ignore the object's prototype across all browsers?

Comment: Unless you're doing things like extending `window.Object.prototype`, you should be good. Even then, you should still be okay, but I'd consider testing that, if that was your intent.

Comment: JSON is [*not* a strict subset of JS](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) (although it's often "close enough").

Answer (score 3):

If you just send data, and not functions, it will work fine. But JSON can only carry *values* - not *functions*. Older browsers (< IE8) doesn't have the JSON object natively, so you will have to provide a fallback solution (frameworks like jQuery implements a fallback automatically).